# Chosen select plugin 'change' event when select is cleared

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I am using chosen.js select plugin and am having one issue I can't seem to figure out.

When I select an option it fires the change event as expected, I then want to reset the chosen control which I accomplish like this:

```
$('#myChosenControl').val('').trigger('liszt:updated');
```

The problem is if I then select the same option again the change event does not fire because it believes the values are the same.

I made a fiddle to demonstrate:

http://jsfiddle.net/Zrb5y/15/

Is there anyway to totally reset the chosen select so that when the same option is selected it will still fire the change event?

Comment: I found this reported as an issue: https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/pull/667

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else looking there is a workaround to this here:

https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/pull/667